# Upper bound on the number of non-zero entries of the product of sparse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

I have two sparse matrices: $A$ of dimension $m \times k$ and $B$ of dimension $k \times n$.

Is there a way to know how many non-zero entries there are in $C =  A B$ without computing $A B$?

I can see that the  trivial upper bound is $m n$ but can I get a better upper bound?

Comment: For many cases that occur in practice, not really.  You just need one column of m ones and one row of n ones to generate (potentially) the maximum number of nonzero entries.  If the first matrix has a lot of zero rows or the second a lot of zero columns, you can narrow the bound a bit.  Gerhard "That's Not Sparse, It's Vacant" Paseman, 2018.04.07.

Comment: The product of two sparse matrices can be dense.

Comment: To get sensible bounds you need some structure of the matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing:

> Given matrices $\mathrm A_1 \in \mathbb R^{m \times k}$ and $\mathrm A_2 \in \mathbb R^{k \times n}$, is there an upper bound on the number of nonzero entries of the $m \times n$ matrix $\mathrm A_1 \mathrm A_2$?

Let Boolean matrices $\mathrm B_1 \in \{0,1\}^{m \times k}$ and $\mathrm B_2 \in \{0,1\}^{k \times n}$ be obtained by applying the function

$$x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \neq 0\\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0\end{cases}$$

to each entry of $\mathrm A_1$ and $\mathrm A_2$, respectively. Note that $\mathrm B_1$ and $\mathrm B_2$ contain information on the **sparsity patterns** of $\mathrm A_1$ and $\mathrm A_2$, respectively. The number of *nonzero* entries of $\mathrm B_1 \mathrm B_2$ provides an **upper bound** on the number of nonzero entries of $\mathrm A_1 \mathrm A_2$.

Since we are interested only in deciding whether an entry is zero or not, let us use Boolean algebra. The cost of deciding whether an entry of $\mathrm B_1 \mathrm B_2$ is zero or not is at most $k$ **AND** operations and $k-1$ **OR** operations. If one is lucky, only **one** AND operation is required.

Thus, the total computational cost is at most $m n (2k-1)$ **logical** operations, which is *cheaper* than performing $m n (2k-1)$ **floating-point** operations (plus counting the number of nonzero entries).